# How to record from 2 microphones to create a virtual environment (Binaural Recording)

Tags: 12.04, sound, microphone, audio-recording

I wish to make a recording using 2 microphones positioned at a distance as described in this wikipedia article on binaural recording so I can make a "3D sound" recording. How can I configure Ubuntu or what should I install in Ubuntu so I can make this doable?

I want to make sound recordings that when the user puts on the headphones the Binaural Recording Effect is experienced.

Similar to the famous [Virtual Barber Shop video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUDTlvagjJA)

Where you put on your headphones and close you eyes and your brain starts to process the environment in a way that you feel you are in that virtual place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably just to record from two mics at once, then merge the two sound files into one stereo file.

---

Possibility one: Use a 2xMono->1xStereo adaptor to plug two analog mics into one mic socket

---

Possibility two:

The first part (record from 2 mics at once): [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/61037/how-to-record-from-multiple-audio-devices-simultaneously/) might help.

Also, maybe there is some trick to do this via pulseaudio

You'll probably need a fancy sound card, or two sound cards (one should note that USB mics usually are also separate sound cards)

The second part (create a stereo file): in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/Audio), it says:

SOX
can do things like combine 2 mono tracks into a stereo file.